# Java Generics with Wildcards Not Compiling

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm having trouble understanding the finer points of Java generics with wildcards. specifically, why doesn't this compile.

```
public class Test {

    abstract class Function<A, B> {
        abstract B call(A a);
    }

    interface PropertyType {
        String bubbles();
    }

    class Apartment implements PropertyType {
        @Override
        public String bubbles() {
            return "bubbles";
        }
    }

    public void invokeFunctionOnAList() {
        List<Apartment> apts = new ArrayList<Apartment>();
        functionLoop(apts, new Function<Apartment, String>() {

            @Override
            String call(Apartment a) {
                return a.bubbles();
            }
        });
    }

    public void functionLoop(List<? extends PropertyType> list, Function<? extends PropertyType, String> t) {
        for (PropertyType p : list) {
            t.call(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see the problem, and most Java compilers will be pretty explicit about it. What errors do you get?

Comment: If you're going to report that something fails to compile, you should *always* include the error message and location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler does not know if you are using same type in List and Function. Therefore you have to tell him this.

Try this:

```
public <C extends PropertyType>void functionLoop(
                         List<C> list, Function<C, String> t) {
  for (C p : list) {
    t.call(p);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, because the subtype of the List need not be the subtype of the Function ?

Comment: Yes, the type of objects in your List must have the same type of your parameter in your call method in Function.

Answer (score 3):

The most formally correct way to put that code actually is

```
public <C extends PropertyType> void functionLoop(
        List<C> list, Function<? super C, String> t) {
    for (C p : list) {
        t.call(p);
    }
}
```

The best explanation of generics I found was on "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch. You can find a small excerpt which can relate to your example in this [presentation](http://devender.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/effectivejava.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

because `call(Apartment a)` should get `Apartment` object as a parameter and you pass a `PropertyType` object. THough `Apartment` is-a `PropertyType`, but `PropertyType` is-NOT-a `Appartment`.